# Redraw view inside of self.view on viewDidLoad() in swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, swift2

I'm working on an app that has a view that is positioned in various places depending on the screen size of it. The size depends on the device. I chose the size of the iPhone 5S. My app will run on an iPad.
See how was the Swift code:

```
class Main: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var viewRect: UIView!

    let DeviceHeigth:CGFloat = 1136 / 2
    let DeviceWith:CGFloat = 640 / 2

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        calcviewRectViewInit()

    }

    func calcviewRectViewInit(){

        let space:CGFloat = 40
        var frame: CGRect = viewRect.frame
        frame.size.height = DeviceHeigth
        frame.size.width = DeviceWith
        frame.origin = CGPoint(x: toolView.frame.width + space, y: space)

        viewRect.frame = frame
    }
```

When you start, the Rect view is not positioned in the sizes and positions - by code. The viewDidLoad is not redrawn the view at runtime.

My question is: **How can redraw the view (viewRect) when starting the app?**

Comment: How about just replacing `DeviceWidth` with `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width` and `DeviceHeight` with`UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the superview's frame as a reference.

For example:

```
var frame: CGRect = viewRect.frame
frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height / 2
frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width / 2
```

I referenced `self.view` instead of just `view` for clarity. `UIViewController` has the `view` property. This can be used where you are attempting to reference the device size.

You should also make sure you have the frame set correctly for the `toolView` prior to building this frame.

Additionally, I would recommend looking at Auto Layout for this particular problem. It was designed to aid in supporting user interfaces on various size screens. Below is a link to more information about it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html